# Android: One way Sync of mobile SQLite database with Online (Oracle) database server

Tags: android, iphone

I am developing an application to Android/ iPhone / BB devices. On 1st launch of application I want to sync with online Oracle database server and download database in SQLite format to mobile's SD Card. Once the download is finished application will work in offline mode without network connection. When there is any update in the server database and user enabled network connection then mobile local database has to sync with the server database and download latest to SD Card. Is this kind of one way sync is possible. If possible can some one guide me.

Comment: yes this is possible & i had done that thing but what you had done till now..???

Comment: I am struck in starting itself. Is there any reference with some sample example.